# Authenticating to AD from a workgroup IIS installation

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

I am using classic ASP (I know I should move on to ASP.NET) and a workgroup IIS installation.  Can I get it to authenticate to AD?  So, far it just won't connect to AD.

It is working on my desktop that is domain joined without any hassles but the same code won't work from the workgroup machine.

```
Session( "signon_domain" ) = UCase( strSignOnDomain )
Session( "signon_userid" ) = LCase( strSignOnUserID )

' Set the AD path to connect to
strADsPath = "WinNT://" & strSignOnDomain

' Bind to the AD path
Set objADsPath = GetObject( strADsPath )

' Get the namespace
strADsNamespace = "WinNT:"

' Bind to the namespace
Set objADsNamespace = GetObject( strADsNamespace )

' Turn on error handling
On Error Resume Next

' Connect to AD with the provided credentials
Set objADsAuthenticate = objADsNamespace.OpenDSObject( strADsPath, strSignOnDomain & "\" & strSignOnUserID, strSignOnPassword, 0 )

' Check for any errors
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ' Specify the error to display
    strMessage = "User ID or password or domain incorrect."
    Session( "signon" ) = ""
Else
    Session( "signon" ) = "successful"
End If

' Turn off error handling
On Error Goto 0

' Clear variables
Set objADsAuthenticate = Nothing
Set objADsNamespace = Nothing
Set objADsPath = Nothing
strADsNamespace = Empty
strADsPath = Empty
```

Expecting a response from AD but instead it isn't connecting to AD at all.

Comment: If the machine is not part of the AD domain, what makes you think this would ever work?

Comment: I was hoping there is a way to make it work.  I know it is possible with ASP.NET.